# Delete all entities in Minecraft without launching the server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

There is over 1 million kelp in my 1.15 server right now and i need to be able to remove them without opening the server for obvious reasons.

Comment: I bet there's also an MCEdit way to do it that is specifically made for this purpose, simply because there seems to be an MCEdit feature/preset/filter/... for basically anything, but I don't know any. Maybe googling relevant terms results in something relevant, maybe not.

Answer (score -2):

To remove item entities from the world use either the server console or with the command

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:item]
```

To remove a specific item, you have to use nbt target selector.
In your case that would be

```
/kill @e[type=minecraft:item, nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:kelp"}}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is definitely not "without starting the game/server".